# Javascript seems to get out of the control flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, controls

I have a problem and I don't know how to fix it ... in the following code - the control seems to never reach the `changePage` command! I guess that's a problem of the control flow in the `addToGlobal` function ... is this possible?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var globalData = {};

    function addToGlobal(name, value) {
        globalData[name] = value;
    };

$('#tempform').submit(function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("preventDefault Temp")

        var form = $(this);

        // add to globalData
        addToGlobal("TemperatureU", form.data('clicked'));

        $.mobile.changePage('#page2', {transition: 'slide'});

    });
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You have a small syntax error. You are missing a closing ) at the end of the ready handler.

The first step for any JS problem should be to check the console for any error messages. I ran your code, and saw the syntax error in the console showing a missing parenthesis.

Comment: sorry I didn't copied the whole code and forgot to put the closing bracket into SO! so I don't think that that's the error!

Comment: The code runs correctly with the missing ), which means it may be an issue in the changePage function itself. Are you getting any errors logged in the console?

Comment: wasn't a problem of the javascript but of the cordova application it is running in ... thanks for the help anyways! :)

Answer (score 1):

The only reason that `addToGlobal` wouldn't run is if `form.data('clicked')` is throwing an error. I suggest adding a few more console.logs around to see what's really going on.

```
console.log(form.data('clicked'));
addToGlobal("TemperatureU", form.data('clicked'));
console.log(globalData);
```